# Make document library check in comments mandatory

Tags: document-library, check-in

What is the easiest way to make the Check In Comments mandatory on a document library in SharePoint 2010?
I've tried an event receiver, but it does not work. I've tried making a custom column but it doesn't work because when you upload a document it requires that field so it fails.

pleeeeease help. I've searched to infinity and beyond for this, and no post, blog or anyone has given a clear answer.

Comment: have you tried the following approach?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715038/sharepoint-2010-document-library-versions-comment

Comment: AHAAA! finally! thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.